# About recompiling diff components of C# program

Tags: c#, csv

I have a question about recompiling different components of C# console app after making changes

1. Program.cs --> needs to be rebuilt to see changes
2. App.config --Not sure
3. Also i have a folder called UserFiles which has a csv file that I refer in my Program.cs file. If I make changes to either App.config or csv file should I recompile the program. Can someone explain to me how this works please?

Thanks
R

Comment: If you Build then just what changed gets rebuilt. If you Rebuild then everything gets rebuilt whether it changed or not.

Comment: Also, what gets built and in what way in visual studio is determined by the build action of the file in question. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @MikeCheel, I use VS2012 and where can I find Build Page?

Comment: In your solution explorer (the window with your solution and project and files and stuff) you select a file and then view the properties window for it (F4).

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct
2. The App.config file is essentially just a XML file  that your program can read settings from when it runs. You don't need to recompile if you make changes to that.
3. No. Your CSV has absolutely nothing to do with the compilation of your program